# How to upload a custom thumbnail for a SharePoint document

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, thumbnails

How do I upload custom thumbnails for document formats not managed by SharePoint?

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-thumbnails?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) of the Graph documentation says that it is possible to "Upload a custom thumbnail for an item", shows how to download standard and custom thumbnails, but doesn't say how to upload one.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059510/upload-custom-thumbnail-to-sharepoint-image-library) talks about the folder `_t` containing the custom thumbnails, but I haven't found any documentation of that folder.

Comment: you're referring the "List thumbnails for a DriveItem" document and they talk about GET call only there. If you need to upload either it should POST, PATCH request. But i failed to see the API call for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this endpoint:

```
PUT /drive/items/{item-id}/thumbnails/0/source/content
```

**Note**: Custom thumbnails are only available on OneDrive Personal.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_thumbnailset_content?view=odsp-graph-online

Comment: I am marking this as answer even if the correct answer should be "it's impossible". I tried this endpoint, but I get a 400 - Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header.